# onclick function to insert data into input field with toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, toggle

I would like to build two buttons with an **onclick function** that will insert "male" or "female" into another input.

The two buttons have background images and need to change background-position when clicked.  I need both buttons to toggle from each other.

Can anyone suggest a solution with javascript or jquery?

```
<input type="button" class="gnM" onclick="???????">
<input type="button" class="gnF" onclick="???????">

<input class="req-string gender" id="gender" name="gender">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must do this with `onclick` then I'd suggest:

```
<input type="button" class="gnM" onclick="$('#gender').val($(this).val())" value="male" />
<input type="button" class="gnM" onclick="$('#gender').val($(this).val())" value="female" />
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DnyDV/).

I'd strongly suggest moving from an `onclick` to a jQuery unobtrusive method, using the `click()` method:

```
​$('.gnM').click(
    function(){
        var that = $(this);
        $('#gender').val(that.val());
        that.css('background-position','bottom right');
    });​​​​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DnyDV/1/).

To allow for toggling:

```
$('.gnM').click(
    function(){
        var that = $(this);
        $('#gender').val(that.val());
        that.siblings().removeClass('active');
        that.toggleClass('active');
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DnyDV/2/).

Or, more concisely:

```
$('.gnM').click(
    function(){
        var that = $(this);
        $('#gender').val(that.val());
        that.toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DnyDV/3/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Thank you, but how would I change the background-position of the two buttons?

Comment: Show your CSS, and explain how you want the `background-position` to change position. Show a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you've tried.

Comment: When I click the male button, the female button should return to its original state and vice versa.  Can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vFsXt/ solution using jQuery, avoid using inline attribute for js

Comment: Thank you, but how would I change the background-position of the button so they toggle off each other?  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you recommend avoiding inline js attributes?

Comment: @Brian Google will give you tonnes of links about it, here is one http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/

Comment: @Erik just set the background position change on the class, so when the class is switch the background position change is applied

Comment: @gillesc Thanks for the link. Please don't tell people to google references that you should have included in your answer. Blanket statements like "avoid inline attributes for js" are poor answers. People frequently simplify code in questions/answers to get to the specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create a css class (`button-toggle-on`) that applies the toggled background-position for the buttons. Then in the button `onclick` toggle the class on the button. For this to work, one needs to be toggled on initially.

```
<input type="button" class="gnM button-toggle-on" onclick="$('#gender').val('male'); $('.gnF, .gnM').toggleClass('button-toggle-on');" /> 
<input type="button" class="gnF" onclick="$('#gender').val('female'); $('.gnF, .gnM').toggleClass('button-toggle-on');" />
```

Comment: If I push the Male Button, will the Female return to its original state and vice versa?  This is the toggle.

Comment: It will now. I didn't realize that they needed to toggle eacher other before.